# voice assistant that can open applications with the help of voice commands in python

Tags: python, voice-recognition

**Hey everyone,
I've been trying to build a voice assistant that can open applications with the help of voice commands in python. Since I'm just a starter I only tried it with google and Wikipedia but it's not working. It only opens Wikipedia, even when I'm telling him to open Google. Can anyone please help me with that? I am on a mac by the way.
Thank you very much**

**my code:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser

speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()


with sr.Microphone() as micro:
    print("Recording...")
    audio = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audio, language="de-DE")
    print(text)
if speech_engine == "Open Google":
    webbrowser.open("https.//google.com")
else:
    webbrowser.open("https://wikipedia.org")´´´
```

Comment: It's because it doesn't recognise google and its else statement hence it opens wikipedia.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, to debug, the first step is to write more comprehensive `if` statement. something like: `if speech_engine == 'open Google': webbrowser.open("https.//google.com") elif speech_engine == "Open Wikipedia": webbrowser.open("https://wikipedia.org") else: print("Unrecoginized Command") `.
The Second step, I think that you should use `if text == 'Open Google'` instead of `if speech_engine == "Open Google"`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. However now the Output just sais: Recording...
Recognizing...
Open Google
Unrecognized Command

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: can you show us full error traceback in by editing your post okay may be language detection problem you can change language by "en" from my code try it

Comment: I changed my programm a little bit so that the assistant is printing "opening google" or "opening wikipedia" when it works. It seems as if the problem changed a little bit. When I'm telling my assistant to open Wikipedia, he does. But when I tell him to open Google, he doesn't. He gives me the output "opening Google" but he doesn't open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if that is a good answer but I found out that the assistant has a problem with executing the command used in the first if-statement. All other commands in the elif-statements work fine. That is now my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser

speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()


with sr.Microphone() as micro:
    print("Recording...")
    audio = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audio, language="en")
    print(text)
if text == 'come on':
    print("I am sorry, Sir")
elif text == 'open Wikipedia':
    webbrowser.open("https://wikipedia.org")
    print("opening Wikipedia")
elif text == 'open Google':
    webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
    print("opening Google")
elif text == 'open stack overflow':
    webbrowser.open("https://stackoverflow.com")
    print("opening Google")
else:
    print("Unrecognized Command")
´´´
```

Comment: Shouldn't all that be inside the with statement

Answer (score 0):

In your code `text` is returing your ouput not `speech_engine` so you shoud change your condition and it will work!

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser

speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()


with sr.Microphone() as micro:
    print("Recording...")
    audio = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audio, language="en")
    print(text)
if text == "Open Google" or text=="Google":
    webbrowser.open("https.//google.com")
else:
    webbrowser.open("https://wikipedia.org")
```

Output:

```
Recording...
Recognizing...
Google
```

Comment: Shouldn't all that be inside the with statement